# Deploying nuxt edge to firebase with function get an error

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js

I try to deploy nuxt project using the latest version of Nuxt which is `nuxt-edge` to firebase. This is my function code.

```
const { Nuxt } = require('nuxt-edge')
const express = require('express')
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

const app = express()

const config = {
  dev: false,
  buildDir: 'nuxt',
  build: {
    extractCSS: true,
    cache: false,
    parallel: true,
    publicPath: '/assets/'
  }
}

const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

const handleRequest = (req, res) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    nuxt.render(req, res, promise => {
      promise.then(resolve).catch(reject)
    })
  })
}

app.use(handleRequest)
exports.jefrydcossr = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

It successfully run locally with `firebase serve --only hosting,function` command. But when I deployed it online and I open the hosting url, I got server error 500.

After I looked at the error log, I got error like this

```
2018-06-14T12:43:26.094Z D jefrydcossr: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: Error: only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/nuxt-edge/node_modules/babel-polyfill/lib/index.js:10:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/nuxt-edge/dist/nuxt-legacy.js:50:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2018-06-14T12:43:26.206Z E jefrydcossr: undefined
2018-06-14T12:51:04.440Z N jefrydcossr: undefined
2018-06-14T12:53:28.052Z N jefrydcossr: undefined
```

The repository of this project here https://github.com/jefrydco/jefrydco-id